# All Array elements into Outlook mailitem

Tags: arrays, vba, outlook

I have an array with a unknown number of elements.

I am trying to find out how can I insert all the array elements into the body of the e-mail that I'll send.

Is there a way I can reference all items of an array ( without knowing  how many elements exist) ?

My code is below

```
Dim MyArray() As String
Dim Msg As Object
Dim item As Object



Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items

olItms.Sort "Received", False 'False = Ascending = Older to newer


i = 0
For Each Msg In olItms
    If Msg.Class = olMail Then
        If InStr(1, Msg.Subject, "1401001LS") > 0 Then

        ReDim Preserve MyArray(i)

        If i = 0 Then
           MyArray(i) = "From: " & Msg.Sender & vbNewLine & "Sent: " & Msg.SentOn & vbNewLine & "To: " & Msg.To & vbNewLine & "CC: " & Msg.CC & vbNewLine & "Subject: " & Msg.Subject & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Msg.Body
        End If


        If i > 0 Then
            MyArray(i) = "From: " & Msg.Sender & vbNewLine & "Sent: " & Msg.SentOn & vbNewLine & "To: " & Msg.To & vbNewLine & "CC: " & Msg.CC & vbNewLine & "Subject: " & Msg.Subject & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Split(Msg.Body, "From: ")(0)
        End If

i = i + 1


        End If
    End If

Next Msg





Unload Me

Done.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: you can find the length of an array by using Ubound(MyArray)

Comment: I am aware of that, but I still cannot figure out a way of inserting all arrays in one Msgbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop through the elements in the array using the method below

```
Dim sContentsOfArray as string
Dim iCnt As Integer
For iCnt = 0 To UBound(MyArray) Step 1
    'access the element at position iCnt and put it at the end of the string
    sContentsOfArray = sContentsOfArray + MyArray (iCnt)
Next iCnt
```

Comment: But in this loop, each element will overwrite the next one, wont it?
What does Step 1 mean?

Comment: no, that loops through each element in the array.  You seriously need to go read up a bit as Arrays and loops are fundamental in programming and it is clear that you do not have a grasp.  I am not trying to be mean but you are setting yourself up for some serious issues later on.

Comment: Thanks, man, I am still learning it.
I got your code but I am not sure you understood my question!

I already have MyArray with the elements all set.
Now I need to create a variable that will store all elements in sequence. This variable will be the Body of the e-mail.

Example: MyArray(0) = January  
         MyArray(1) = February
         MyArray(2) = March

VariableMsg =  MyArray(0) & MyArray(1) & MyArray(2)


The thing is: Each time the code runs, I'll have a different number of elements in the array.

Comment: I understood your question.  I dont think you under stand what the code I gave you does.  I updated it to show how you put all the elements into a string.  You can then assign that string the the body of the email message.

Comment: Thanks, man. It worked fine!

One more thing: The code will send me an e-mail with some bodies. It's working, but the text is not formatted when I receive the e-mail.
Is there a way to keep the original format (bold, italic, font) ?